# C getting an "unknown type " error when i try to assign a struct node in a struct node

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, scope, typedef

I am trying to make a struct Node, that links to other Nodes. in the code below

```
typedef struct Node{

   Node *children[10];

}Node;
```

When i try and compile i get the error

**Error unknown type name 'Node'**

I'm pretty sure i should be able to assign a Node from inside the Struct Node. Can anyone explain why this isnt working.

Answer (score 2):

Within the structure definition the name `Node` is yet undefined. There is defined only the type specifier `struct Node`. So write

```
typedef struct Node{

   struct Node *children[10];

}Node;
```

Or you could write

```
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node
{
    Node *children[10];
};
```

Comment: Thats perfect thanks.

Comment: @user1003967 If the problem resolved you can close the question selecting the best answer. In this case your reputation will be increased.:)